# How to select and sum values from an object?

Tags: jquery, json

Say I have an object being returned from a method that contains an array of javascript objects (json).  How can I sum the values of a specific field.

From the array below, I want the sum of the "charge" values and formatted as currency or at least limited to 2 decimal places.

```
data = 
[
    {
        "OrderNum" : "T88477", 
        "Charge" : "145.25", 
        "phone" : "555-555-5555"
    },
    {
        "OrderNum" : "T89477", 
        "Charge" : "35.45", 
        "phone" : "111-555-5555"
    }
];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go with a solution

```js
var data = 
[
    {
        "OrderNum" : "T88477", 
        "Charge" : "145.25", 
        "phone" : "555-555-5555"
    },
    {
        "OrderNum" : "T89477", 
        "Charge" : "35.45", 
        "phone" : "111-555-5555"
    }
];

var sum = 0;

for(var i=0; i<data.length; i++){
  sum += parseFloat(data[i].Charge);
}

console.log("Total: " + sum.toFixed(2));
```

Since the values are stored as `string`, you need to use `parseFloat` for converting it to float.

For upto 2 decimal use `.toFixed(2)`

Hope this will help you.